# Using an if() statement within a for() loop

Tags: r

A seemingly simple R task has got me stumped…  I have a Number field and a TrueFalse field in a data.frame as seen here.

```
#Make Data
TrueFalse <- rep(c("TRUE","TRUE", "FALSE"),10)
Number <- seq(1, length(TrueFalse),3)
Table <- as.data.frame(cbind(TrueFalse, Number))
```

look at the `head()`

```
head(Table)
```

I am trying to create a new column that contains values from the Numbers column if the TrueFalse field is TRUE.
In a meta code:

For each row, NewField ==Number if TrueFalse = True, else nothing (ie. Leave as NA)

My working code is below.  While searches have been productive, I am still missing a few steps.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
#for() loop using if()
NewField <- rep("NA", nrow(Table))
for (i in 1:nrow(NewField)){
    if(Table$TrueFalse[i] == "TRUE")
        {NewField[i] <- Table$Number[i]}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't want to `cbind` your columns before converting to a data frame. `cbind` will force the result to whatever data type is compatible with all your columns, so in this case, it'll turn your `Number` variable into character. Probably not what you want, if not now, then eventually.

Second, R has a logical data type, so you should use it. Especially if you have values called "TRUE" and "FALSE".

Thus:

```
TrueFalse <- rep(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),10)
Table <- data.frame(TrueFalse, Number)

Table$NewField <- ifelse(Table$TrueFalse, Table$Number, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line. For example:

```
Table$NewField <- ifelse(Table$TrueFalse=="TRUE",Table$Number,-1)
```

Also, if you had used `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of "TRUE" and "FALSE", you wouldn't need to use the equality test either.